# How to solve missing InjectedFieldSignature Error implementing Dagger 2 in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, kapt

I have implemented dependency injection in android before using dagger 2 but, recently, I have tried to use it in a new project but I get the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol
> import dagger.internal.InjectedFieldSignature;
> ^
> symbol:   class InjectedFieldSignature
> location: package dagger.internal/location/to/App_MembersInjector.java:30: error: cannot find symbol

Here is my Application component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        (AndroidInjectionModule::class),
        (VmModule::class),
        (InjectorModule::class),
    ]

)
interface ApplicationComponent: AndroidInjector<Application> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder{
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: App): Builder
    fun build() : ApplicationComponent
}

    fun inject(home: Home)
}
```

Then in my App class:

```
class App: Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var  anAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>



override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this)
}

override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> {
    return anAndroidInjector
}

}
```

Then the injector module:

```
@Module
abstract class InjectorModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): Home
}
```

The following is a small excerpt of my app Gradle to show the dagger version:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28'
```

If you have any clue, kindly let me know where the problem might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Dagger artifact versions don't match.  Specifically, you are using `dagger-compiler:2.28` to generate code, but including an dependency on Dagger 2.24 instead.

In the specific case of `dagger.internal.InjectedFieldSignature`, that class appears to have been introduced in Dagger version 2.25.3.  Any later version of the Dagger compiler will expect that `InjectedFieldSignature` exists and can be used in generated code.  However, since you're only including Dagger 2.24 in your project, the generated code ends up referring to a class that doesn't exist.

To fix this, make sure all of your Dagger dependencies use the same version.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the problem. It works perfectly now.